# Inferring object structure and type of object properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need to infer object structure and properties from a return result of the function.

When the function returns I need the same structure that I have put in but the properties on those keys need to be of certain `type` or `interface`

```
interface Validated{
    error:boolean
    missing:boolean
    validated:boolean
}

interface Result<T>{
    error:boolean,
    struct:T
}

const testObj ={
    d1:{
        d2:{
            name:'jack'
        }
    }
}

function test<T>(obj:T):Result<T>{
    return {
        error: false,
        struct: {
            d1: {
                d2: {
                    name: {
                        error: false,
                        missing: false,
                        validated: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

const result = test(testObj)

//result.struct.d1.d2.name // works

// result.struct.d1.d1.name.validated // does not work
```

When the function returns the result, I can go through the structure that I have passed in to the function `result.d1.d2.name`

However I need the `name` property to be inferred as `Validated` interface `result.d1.d2.name.validated`

So the question is how to get the `Validated` interface on to the `name` property, no matter the depth of the property.

[TS playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAStAzgVwDaQA8AKgHwDewaNacsA9rAFwBGDD+0i4ANNbWyRYuZJGYlgAXxAQYCFOgBqifKAAmiGOqq06sRi3adu4ATQC2obNggBzNhy49zaAG6qNW6OscmXMsDIDOBCaDBCAPKsAFZoALy6tOoAjMxJejTqAEzprpm04IgW0MwA5DEoANZl+bQyejKB8LjgYqAh4TjE5AAUDLESAJTMWHiEpJSusNCQuLDgaBmZ9EzMaEj42ND8BTRCImLry3toqcd1p1m5S5dXekUlF-cvtKssG6rbu68vVjb2dabb53X60DxqTTadbCXDQUEvBpgtBI+6ozLoqQAbmkIBAwVCkDQM3GRPiXSEvQikGiMSGIAA9AziTgCJAAHQHUQc1LsnLsx7woA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a type recursively in combination with a conditional should do the trick:

```js
type DeepValidated<T> = T extends object
    ? { [K in keyof T]: DeepValidated<T[K]> }
    : Validated

interface Result<T>{
    error:boolean,
    struct:DeepValidated<T>
}
```

`DeepValidated` checks whether `T` is an object. If that's the case it iterates over all properties and applies `DeepValidated` recursively. Otherwise it returns `Validated` effectively replacing the original type `T`.

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAStAzgVwDaQA8AKgHwDewaNacsA9rAFwBGDD+0i4ANNbWyRYuZJGYARaNAAOANUT5QAE0QxlpMsAC+ICDAQp0CpavVVadWIxbtO3cAJoBbUNmwQA5mw5ceTtAA3RRU1aGUfe39dYEgATxl0KVkTUPVNNABeNBI6AA8YcGVsNAZWACtoMQCAfjQKNABtAGk0CDQAa2g4hngcgF1mNGT5ELNw0hb+sjRdSyHU8eUQZAZwITQYIQB5CqyLWmUARmYDyxplACZTgPPacERnaGYAcnKUDpfb2jmfnRB4LhwGJQGtNjhiOQABRlcrMEgASmYWDwhE0ZzQsGgkFwsHA9W+NHoTCGSHw2Gg-DuNCEIjEQwx1LQxwZhKZzOuBPZ3LQDyerJ5gqsNlJigpVKF3Nc7i8ovJlLZkpowVMYQimxE0EVPN+kt17P1ln12gA3P8QMBVutIJicAQbdktpAoU7duUESAAPSe22oyAAOlpogDx39V39fK1QA)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want for a property of a wanted name to replace its value type, no matter the depth of the object.

This is a solution:

```js
/**
 * From object O,
 * Replace the value type of keys KV,
 * By the type V
 */
type ReplaceType<O extends object, KV, V> = {
    [K in keyof O]: K extends KV ? V : (
        O[K] extends object ? ReplaceType<O[K], KV, V> : O[K]
    );
};

interface Result<T extends object>{
    error: boolean,
    struct: ReplaceType<T, 'name', Validated>;
}
```

The difference with the @lukasgeiter answer is that I change only the wanted field, other ones stay as is.

Comment: I should have made it clear that the `name` property is just an example. There are going to an arbitrary number of properties.